# In batch, what does /hrkvy mean?

Tags: batch

I'm referencing the code found in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399124/batch-file-to-copy-files-listed-in-a-text-file-from-source-to-destination-keepin

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "W:\Parrot EN VO\Copylist.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4test"
```

When I run the code as is using my file path, it works perfectly. But when I changed the `/hrkvy` to something arbitrary, the code doesn't seem to run. I can't find any references to the path online so can someone explain what it actually means?

Comment: Hrkvy is not a path, it is a list of parameters for `xcopy`. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with batch.
It is the xcopy command that you are looking for.

XCOPY /? gives you this same information.

/H           Copies hidden and system files also.

/R           Overwrites read-only files.

/K           Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.

/V           Verifies the size of each new file.

/Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Answer (score 1):

Lets analyze the command step by step

```
1. for 
2.     /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a 
3. in 
4.     ('type "W:\Parrot EN VO\Copylist.txt"') 
5. do 
6.     xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "W:\Parrot EN VO\VO4test"
```

for is a command that processes the command after do with a set of parameters.
the 6th line is the command being executed. /hrkvy is part of the parameters of the xcopy command. You can see xcopy /? to see what parameters are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find any references to the path online.

It isn't a path. Windows uses `\` as path separators, while `/` are typically used under Unix-like operating systems (e.g. Linux, MacOS).

> When I changed the `/hrkvy` to something arbitrary, the code doesn't seem to run.

That's because `/hrkvy` are options to the `xcopy` command and the random values you are typing likely aren't. Microsoft command line programs use `/` to denote options (e.g. `dir /x`). However, the options do not have to be listed individually (though they might be for readability).

In your example, this [overview of the xcopy command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) indicates the following relevant options are in use:

```
/H   Copy hidden and system files and folders (default=N).

/R   Overwrite read-only files.

/K   Copy attributes. XCOPY will otherwise reset read-only attributes.

/V   Verify that the new files are readable.

/Y   Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file. Can be preset in the COPYCMD env variable.
```

These same options (and more) can be displayed with `xcopy /?`.